# How can I make a flexbox parent have the width of its children?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a parent element, with two elements inside:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
     one
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    two
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, the .parent is 100% wide. I would like it only to be the width of the two children.

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

**How can I make the parent to be the width of it's contents, and not wider?**

[See codepen for a live demo.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOgdEg)

Comment: I've just checked this for answers for the first time since asking the question - what's happened here? It looks like two people answering had an argument then decided to downvote the question?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Change the parent's display from `flex` to `inline-flex`.

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    one
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    two
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know - I'm not the downvoter - but thanks for you answer and sorry people are being so badly behaved.

Comment: I'm trying this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L4sqdjkd/4//) and it's not working. Any ideas as to why? using inline-flex compresses it and makes its width smaller than the child.

Comment: @user3494047 Because you have Bootstrap in the mix adding its own styling

Comment: @j08691 I tried removing bootstrap, but that didn't help. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5wksaj72/) is an updated fiddle

Comment: also as you can see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jVPMVx) if you give the two child div's a flex-basis width, it doesn't work to use inline-flex